# How to increase and resolve the session and connection timeout in Spring boot API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, https, java-8

**Can you tell me how to extend Session timed out. i have one API it is working fine when it in local Machine but after deployment i am getting error Session and connection timeout it is happening because if you hit any https request the api should return response within 60 seconds but my Api is taking 5-10 minutes to execute task. so could you guide me how to increase this time limit. I am using Spring Boot 2.0 and Java 8.**

Here is error:

```
2020-03-02 06:44:08.682 ERROR 57 --- [nio-8443-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2146) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1544) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1293) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:151) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:143) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1749) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1755) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:171) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168) ~[groovy-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:255) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy) ~[rest-assured-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.amex.arenalytics.service.impl.ResponseRestServiceImpl.getApplicationInforFromKibana(ResponseRestServiceImpl.java:83) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amex.arenalytics.controller.ResponseRestClientController.getApplicationInfoFromKibana(ResponseRestClientController.java:43) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
```

Comment: share the code that you have written. Also the Stack-trace of the exception.

Comment: I updated error for above problem.. I will post all code also please have a look if you are able to understand .

i tried too many solution like:-
serever.servlet.session.timeout:30 m -

Comment: @dassum please have a look

Comment: @dassum above issues I was getting because of Security Restrictions. I resolved above issues